# How to filtering metabase widget via external button

Tags: html, filter, dashboard, metabase

Hy everyone,

i'm trying to setup a dashboard in metabase which will be embedded into an external portal of our client.
One of the requirements is that all the widget that will be exporting must be filtered from external buttons that represent some specific field of table in the datamart.
So, the widget cannot be filtered from metabase directly, but via a third party script.
I know that is possibile to pre-filter data represented by a widget thanks to signed parameters (https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/administration-guide/13-embedding.html)

So, i wanna know if this function will work also with my request.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out.
Using LOCKED PARAMETERS, you can do it.

ref [https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/administration-guide/13-embedding.html#:~:text=If%20you%20wish%20to%20have,the%20embedding%20application's%20server%20code](https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/administration-guide/13-embedding.html#:%7E:text=If%20you%20wish%20to%20have,the%20embedding%20application%27s%20server%20code).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).